# How to use build-specific files or resources in Visual Studio for C# projects?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resources, buildconfiguration

Is there a way in Visual Studio to define some files or resources to be used only in specific build configurations? We use many `#if DEBUG` clauses to add debug-only code, but the same can't be done in a .config xml file, for example. Is there a way to define two versions of that file to be used, depending on whether the build configuration is set to Debug or Release?

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12084002/how-to-set-strings-xml-values-at-build-time) that describes what I'm looking to do but for Android using Ant. Is there a similar mechanism for Visual Studio and .NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way in Visual Studio to define some files or resources to be used only in specific build configurations?

According to this doc: [MSBuild concepts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-concepts?view=vs-2019) which mentioned “MSBuild provides a basic XML schema that you can use to control how the build platform builds software.”, I think MSBuild could help you solve this issue.

> Is there a way to define two versions of that file to be used, depending on whether the build configuration is set to Debug or Release?

MSBuild has four parts: properties, items, tasks, and targets. For this issue you may need to focus on “items” part.

Solution:

You could add this command line “Condition=”’$(Configuration)’==’Debug’” and “Condition=”’$(Configuration)’==’Release’” to control when(Debug/Release) to use different versions of resources.

Refer to following screenshot, and this link([List of common properties and parameters-- Condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019#list-of-common-properties-and-parameters)).

[image]

Comment: Amazing! Exactly what I was looking for! However, I see how I can include some files in Debug and other files in Release, but if both versions of the file are called "MyFile.config", how can I use the solution you described to include a version or the other? Thanks!

Comment: @DCD You can try to use `<Content … Include=”XXX\XXX\MyFile.config”/>` to specified the path of your different .config files. Besides, you can also consider renaming the .config file such as “MyFile.Debug.config” and “MyFile.Release.config”. BTW, you can refer to this doc: [Choose element(MSBuild)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/choose-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019) and maybe it’s another approach.

Comment: works perfectly! Thanks! Do you think you could add that little bit of information to your answer? I think it would make it more complete. Thanks again!